# Ubuntu 12.04 booting in command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-12.04, gui

I just restarted my Ubuntu OS and now, for some reason, my Ubunut 12.04 boots in command line...without the GUI?

I use Wubi and haven't really done anything out of the ordinary. I've managed to get the GUI running by using `startx` via the command line that appears when Ubuntu boots, but how can I revert back to the GUI boot?

Even after using `startx` a lot of the GUI is missing...top bar, applications panel...etc

Comment: Use `unity` or `lightdm`(for login screen) instead of starting the X window system

Comment: Did you check, your system architecture compatible for Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: If X is failing to start for some reason, you should find more information in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `sudo lightdm`, `startx`, `sudo startx`, or `sudo gdm` in that order of preference(Use the first that works). You may then try to set it up as the last entry in the system-wide `crontab`(See http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg28t5.htm)

Comment: What does `crontab` have to do with anything? This should be set in a script in `/etc/rc5.d/` or whatev er the Ubuntu equivalent is. Cron should not be used to launch a login manager.